# creating grouped and sub grouped drop down list Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a drop down list in angularJS that is populated by a Json. I need groups and subgroups. However I'm running into trouble when I need to open a group inside of my ng-repeat. I'm using buttons so all items including headings can be selected and showing divs based on conditions.

HTML & Angular code:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('cdeApp')
    .component('advCrimeSelect', {
      controller: AdvCrimeSelectController,
      templateUrl: 'src/components/advCrimeSelect/index.html',
      bindings: { onChanges: '<', crimes: '<', selectedCrime: '<', groups: '<'}
    });

  AdvCrimeSelectController.$inject = ['$log'];
  function AdvCrimeSelectController($log) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = construct;

    function construct() {
      vm.crimeChanged = crimeChanged;
      vm.openDdl = openDdl;
      vm.openGroups = openGroups;
      vm.ddlOpen = false;
      vm.openPerson = false;
      vm.openProperty = false;
      vm.openSociety = false;
      vm.groupName = " ";
    }

    function crimeChanged() {
      if (vm.onChanges)
        vm.onChanges({ crime: vm.selectedCrime });
    }

    function openDdl(){
      if(vm.ddlOpen == false)
        vm.ddlOpen = true;
      else {
        vm.ddlOpen = false;
      }
    }

    function openGroups(group){
      vm.groupName = group;
      console.log(vm.groupName);
    }

  }
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <button ng-click="$ctrl.openDdl()" class="sans-serif col-12 field field-sm select border-blue">
    {{$ctrl.selectedCrime.crime}}</button>
    <div ng-show="$ctrl.ddlOpen" ng-repeat="g in $ctrl.groups">
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.openGroups(g.id)" class="sans-serif col-12 field select field-sm border-blue">
        {{g.text}}</button>
        <div ng-show="{{g.id}} == $ctrl.groupName">stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The compare on the ng-show inside of the loop below the button returns the same value when clicked as well as with g.id. So I'm not sure why my ng-show isn't showing the div with "stuff" at all. The conditional should be true whenever a group is clicked.

Comment: You define functions, but don't attach them to the controller instance.
Try
`vm.crimeChanged = function...`

Comment: @netoctone the functions are working. crimeChanged isn't used yet. In this instance I'm more wondering why in my html the ng-show when comparing two values that are the same are not showing. When i click on one thus setting groupName to a value it's not showing the div that g.id has the matching value for.

Comment: The other possible reason is that `{{g.id}} == $ctrl.groupName` expression fails for non-digit id values.
Try `g.id == $ctrl.groupName` instead.

Comment: @netoctone that fixed it. Oddly enough it comes up in the console as g.id which is why i initially put the {{}} but thank you for your help!